# How to set the props data in the state of material-ui dialog when the dialog open in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the props data in the state of material-ui dialog when the dialog open and the button that opens the dialog is in a separate page and the dialog is in another page. But i am not able do it , but i am struggling with this. Please tell me its answer.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component{
    state ={
        data:{
            id:"20",
            name:"aman",
            email:"aman@gmail.com"
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <button>Dialog Open</button>
                <Dialog data={this.state.data} />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant set custom attributes/props which are other than requested props by dialog component...

Comment: check the dialog component api documentation what actually props needed.... https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/

Comment: Can't we set the data of the props to the state of the dialog?

Comment: you can set the state externally of any third party component until it provides any api to do that...

Answer (score 1):

The dialog component doesn't have data prop

What you probably want is to show that info inside it?

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";

function CustomDialog({ name, lastname, open, handleClose }) {
  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
      <span>{name}</span>
      <span>{lastname}</span>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default function DraggableDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <CustomDialog
        open={open}
        handleClose={handleClose}
        name="Nome"
        lastname="Lastname"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Take a look at [Dialog API](https://material-ui.com/pt/api/dialog/)

Comment: But we have to set it in the dialog state.

Comment: What do you mean by dialog state?

Comment: Are you confusing props with state? If you want to pass it via props you must create an `CustomDialog` that has a state that is controlled. I am going to modify my answer to this, check it

Comment: But in my code, the button that opens the dialog is in a separate page and the dialog is in another page.

Comment: You can pass props through the components or depends on the case use context API